# Creating Multiple Iterations of JSON in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

New to Rails so I apologize if this is a silly question.

I currently have an application in Rails that renders JSON output to  javascript framework 'jsTree', but I am only able to get one 'tree' worth of information because I am creating, deleting, etc. the nodes themselves in the tree using ajax pointed at the correct route.

I would like to be able to have a function that creates an entirely new set of JSON data for use with other individual trees (stated another way, upon creation of an object with a view containing the jsTree client-side code in the view, I would like to associate different JSON information with that object/tree).

If someone could explain the logic of how I might go about this or point me in the direction of a tutorial/other resources, that would be very helpful.

Controller for the JSON

```
class JsonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_json, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /jsons
  # GET /jsons.json
  def index
    @jsons = Json.all

    render json: @jsons
  end

  # GET /jsons/1
  # GET /jsons/1.json
  def show
    render json: @json
  end

  # POST /jsons
  # POST /jsons.json
  def create
    @json = Json.new(json_params)

    if @json.save
      render json: @json, status: :created, location: @json
    else
      render json: @json.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jsons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jsons/1.json
  def update
    @json = Json.find(params[:id])

    if @json.update(json_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @json.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jsons/1
  # DELETE /jsons/1.json
  def destroy
    @json.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_json
      @json = Json.find(params[:id])
    end

    def json_params
      params.require(:json).permit(:text, :parent, :id)
    end
end
```

Each dashboard object should have its own set of JSON but only one is created for the entire application at the moment via the controller above.

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    # Requires user to be signed in 
    def index
        @dashboards = Dashboard.all
    end

    def new
        @dashboard = Dashboard.new
    end

    def edit
      @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @dashboard = Dashboard.new(dashboard_params)
        @dashboard.save
        if @dashboard.save
            redirect_to :action => :index
        else
            render :action => new
        end
    end

    def update
      @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])

      if @dashboard.update(dashboard_params)
        redirect_to :action => :index
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def show
        @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])
      end

    private 
    def dashboard_params 
        params.require(:dashboard).permit(:title, :description) 
    end
end
```

Comment: You should post some code that shows what you are currently doing and what you have tried.  Otherwise you are basically asking "How long is a piece of string"

Comment: The code has just been updated

Comment: Can you explain this line:  "Each dashboard object should have its own set of JSON but only one is created for the entire application at the moment via the controller above."

Comment: Sure! When a dashboard object is created, I want to have its view referencing its own set of JSON, rather than only being able to reference the single set of JSON at /jsons/ (url defined in route)